# Clean Code: SRP and Open/Closed when fetching data from web services

Tags: c#, web-services, oop, solid-principles

When I'm developing, I usually try to follow the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles.
Usually you have an interface that all affected classes implement and then use the interface as a parameter when making further calculations.

My question is how can this be achieved when calling, for example, a web service? The code below is not very lean and does NOT indeed meet the Single Responsibility Pattern and the Open/Closed Principle.

How would you re-design the following code to follow SRP and O/C:

```
    public class Fetch
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            var url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=NNKOjkoul8n1CH18TWA9gwngW1s1SmjESPjNoUFo";
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var parsedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Nasa>(data);

            if(parsedData.media_type.Equals("image"))
            {
                CreateImage(parsedData);
            }

            if (parsedData.media_type.Equals("video"))
            {
                CreateVideo(parsedData);
            }

            if (parsedData.media_type.Equals("text"))
            {
                CreateText(parsedData);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Nasa
    {
        public string copyright { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string explanation { get; set; }
        public string hdurl { get; set; }
        public string media_type { get; set; }
        public string service_version { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }
```

(The Api key is taken from Nasa's example site so don't worry about exposing it. The async part using `.Result` is just for this example)

Comment: This would be better off on codereview

Comment: This is not a code we are using. It´s only a general problem/discussion around Clean Code and Web Services.

Comment: It's still a codereview (programmers at a push) question - you've posted functioning code and are asking how to improve it from a standards perspective. Whether or not you're actually using the code doesn't really matter.

Comment: Aha, it´s on Stack exchange. I thought you meant internal code review at my company :)

Comment: Maybe I should've posted a link :P

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing much about your needs, or how the `CreateVideo(item)` and `CreateImage(item)` works, you can use this as a starting point.

Please note that if you are using a dependency container (like Simple Injector, love it!) much of the dependencies in the following can be provided by the container.

```
public class Nasa
{
    public string copyright { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string explanation { get; set; }
    public string hdurl { get; set; }
    public string media_type { get; set; }
    public string service_version { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public interface ITransformFetch<in T>
{
    void Transform(T data);
}

public interface IFetch<T> 
{
    T Fetch();
}

public class NasaFetcher : IFetch<Nasa>
{
    private const string NasaUrl = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=NNKOjkoul8n1CH18TWA9gwngW1s1SmjESPjNoUFo";

    private readonly IHttpClientWrapper _client;

    public NasaFetcher(IHttpClientWrapper client)
    {
        _clientFactory = client;
    }

    public Nasa Fetch()
    {
        var response = _client.GetAsync(NasaUrl).Result;
        var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Nasa>(data);
    }
}

public class NasaFetchImageTransformer : ITransformFetch<Nasa>
{
    public void Transform(Nasa data)
    {
        // transform data
    }
}

public class NasaFetchVideoTransformer : ITransformFetch<Nasa>
{
    public void Transform(Nasa data)
    {
        // transform data
    }
}

public class NasaFetcherTransformerDecorator : IFetch<Nasa>
{
    private readonly IFetch<Nasa> _fetcher;

    public NasaFetcherTransformerDecorator(IFetch<Nasa> fetcher)
    {
        _fetcher = fetcher;
    }

    public Nasa Fetch()
    {
        var result = _fetcher.Fetch();
        if (result != null)
        {
            switch (result.media_type)
            {
                case "image":
                    var nasaFetchImageTransformer = new NasaFetchImageTransformer();
                    nasaFetchImageTransformer.Transform(result);
                    break;

                case "video":
                    var nasaFetchVideoTransformer = new NasaFetchVideoTransformer();
                    nasaFetchVideoTransformer.Transform(result);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void TestNasaFetcher()
    {
        var data = new NasaFetcherTransformerDecorator(new NasaFetcher(new HttpClientWrapper()));
        var nasa = data.Fetch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, so if the API adds a new media type, we have the add a new Transformen and then add a new `case` in the switch. Isn't this breaking the `Open/Close Principle`?

Comment: You could also just keep making decorators for each transformer and wrap the object - most likely using a IoC container.